# PDF figure as A4 landscape page

Tags: floats, pdf

I have a map with a given scale as a PDF in A4 that I want to insert as a figure (with a figure caption) in a document. Since the map has a scale (1:50000), I want the figure to fill the whole page and the figure caption to be on the next page. The map is in landscape.

I have tried this:

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{bedrock-map_v1_p1.pdf}
\caption{test}
\label{fig:bedrockmap_whole}
\end{figure}

Now, the map is not in the right scale, and the page is not in landscape. How can I fix this?

Comment: remove `figure` environment and just use `\rotatebox{90}{\includegraphics{....}` then  use `\captionof{figure}{...}`  using catption or capt-of packages